# Ubuntu alias rename directory issue

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, alias, regex

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr installed in my system.

I have created following alias in my '~/.bashrc' file to make renaming directories recursively in current folder, as easy to use short command.

```
renamedirs() {
    find . -depth -type d -not -name '.' -exec rename 's/$1/$2/' {} +
}
alias rendirs=renamedirs
```

I already did `source ~/.bashrc` thing.

But when I run this alias in below manner,

```
rendirs Olddir Newdir
```

I get following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $1 in regexp compilation at (eval 33) line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $2 in substitution iterator at (eval 33) line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $1 in regexp compilation at (eval 34) line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $2 in substitution iterator at (eval 34) line 1.
...
...
```

Can anybody let me know what's wrong here.

Comment: Why do you name your function `renamedirs` just to create an alias to call it `rendirs`? You should directly name the function `rendirs`

Comment: The primary issue is that shell variables are not expanded when enclosed in quotes: so literal `$1` and `$2` are being passed to the `rename` expression (where they're being interpreted as - uninitialized - regex backreferences). There may be other issues with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, but that seems to be irrelevant about the issue, I think issue is related to formatting of the Regexp expression.

Comment: Also, what are `$1` and `$2` supposed to be? The arguments of the function? Then you shouldn't use single quotes. `$1` and `$2` have their meaning in Perl regex. Also: `-mindepth 1` better than `-not -name '.'`

Comment: $1 and $2 are bash arguments, maybe combining them with regexp caused this error.

Comment: Done, double quotes help in this scenario. Did this and issue revoled. ` find . -depth -type d -not -name '.' -exec rename "s/$1/$2/" {} +`

Comment: Actually I don't recommend using `rename` for this at all (at least not unless you change `-exec` to `-execdir` **and** anchor the `$1`); it may give undesired results for example if the name or path *contains* `$1` anywhere within it

Comment: Probably what you actually want is something like `find . -depth -type d -name "$1" -execdir mv -nT -- {} "$2" \;`

Answer (score 1):

Bash makes a difference between single quotes `'...'` and double quotes `"..."`.

Single quotes cause the enclosed text to be taken literally while double quotes allow various interpretations of the string like variable expansion.

You must use double quotes if you have `$x`-like Bash variables in your string which you want to be expanded.

Additionally, directly name your function `rendirs` and do not use an alias to add a second name if the first one is not going to be used.

```
rendirs() {
    find . -depth -type d -not -name '.' -exec rename "s/$1/$2/" {} +
}
```

Comment: Ok, even though I answered myself in comment I will accept yours, just tell me please, if I alias like `alias name=name() {...}` is it correct ? It shouldn't need to be different ?

Comment: @VickyDev why do you need an alias at all?